# Добавить кнопку скачивания на сайт

Tags: python

Есть сайт с позициями, нужно добавить кнопку "скачать в пдф", что бы скачивались только выбранные позиции, шапка и подвал. Как можно это реализовать? И с помощью с чего?

Comment: Что вас побудило дать вопросу метку "python"?

Comment: мне подсказали что это делается с помощью пайтон

Comment: А что, с Java не получится или на плюсах?

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью `JavaScript` собирать нужную инфу и по клику на вашу кнопку её отправлять на сервер. Например, есть форма `id="myForm"` в HTML-шаблоне с кнопкой `id="my-button"`. Здесь `"some_url"` - это параметр `name` в файле `urls.py` для `Django`.

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'some_url' %}">

<button type="submit" id="my-button">Кнопка</button>

</form>
```

И из этой формы `jQuery-запрос` по нажатию на кнопку посылает всю инфу на сервер в виде `JSON`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-button").click(function() {
        var mydata = $("#myForm").serialize(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "js_url",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: mydata,
            success : function(json) {
                alert("Successfully sent the URL to Django");
            },
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: а за сколько вы сможете реализовать это на моем сайте?